# Link to a browser's settings

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a site where I require a  to ask the user to enable javascript..
is there a way I can link the browser's setting page in it.

for example:

```html
<noscript>
    <div>Please enable javascript <a href="**(Link to the browser's JavaScript settings)**">Click here to enable javascript</a></div>
</noscript>
```

This is what I had tried but it didn't work...

```html
<noscript>
  <div>Please enable javascript
    <a href="chrome://settings/content/javascript">Click here to enable javascript</a>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: What have you already tried? It's a good idea to include what you've already tried doing to overcome this, and what problems you're facing. This will make your question more focused and easier to answer concisely.

Comment: [You can't](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171572/why-cant-i-open-the-chrome-settings-page-from-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure this cannot work via href.
Also doesn't work via window.open('url').

Based on the errors I am seeing, I don't thing you can get there without a positive, separate act by the user. Which means you could TELL them what they could type, but you can't do it for them.

---

**Examples: the settings pages for Firefox and Chrome**

On Chrome the general settings page is 'chrome://settings'
For JavaScript it is 'chrome://settings/content/javascript'

On Firefox the page is 'about:config'
Getting to the relevant JavaScript page relies on search, or knowing the setting name (javascript.enabled)

---

**Trying with ...**

Clicking any of those settings page urls as links does nothing, or just plain fails.

Trying it on Chrome: the first one (which is for Firefox anyway) does create a new tab with an error in it but that's all.

Trying it on Firefox: no visible results. The console shows various errors such as 
`Security Error: Content at https://nthworld.com/pt/d/sob.php may not load or link to ...`

**Trying with window.open()**
Making them into clickable buttons that try to use window.open() with their respective 'url' values results in failure as well.

On Chrome, window.open('chrome://settings') produces this error:
`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/`

Same for window.open('chrome://settings/content/javascript'):
`sob.php:26 Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/content/javascript`

On Firefox for window.open('about:config'):
`Error: Access to 'about:config' from script denied`

```js
 $('#about').on('click', function () {
   window.open("about:config");
  });
  $('#chrome1').on('click', function () {
   window.open("chrome://settings");
  });
  $('#chrome2').on('click', function () {
   window.open("chrome://settings/content/javascript");
  });
```

```css
button {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="about:config" target="ff">about:config</a></p>
 <p><a href="chrome://settings" target="ch">chrome://settings</a></p>
 <p><a href="chrome://settings/content/javascript" target="ch">chrome://settings/content/javascript</a></p>
 <button id="about">about:config</button>
 <button id="chrome1">chrome://settings</button>
 <button id="chrome2">chrome://settings/content/javascript</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, Sir..@Yishmeray

Comment: you are welcome! if this is helpful, please consider indicating so by an upvote or accepting the answer - or something! Totally your choice of course

Comment: Sir ...I did upvote but stack overflow doesn't consider mine until I get atleast 15 reputation points