# Why doesn't <a href="chrome://settings/content/popups">chrome://settings/content/popups</a> open link?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I can open a Chrome setting page by typing *chrome://settings/content/popups* in the address of Chrome.

When I try to use the following code A to open Chrome setting page by clicking the link of HTML, I find the  Chrome setting page can't be opened, why?

**Code A**

```
 <a href="chrome://settings/content/popups">chrome://settings/content/popups</a>
```

Comment: Developer console says "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/content/popups", which I would assume its due to security reasons (User local data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with Javascript (`window.open()`) or HTML as this presents a security risk. For example, this could be used to trick visitors of a site to change settings in order to make it easier to launch an attack of some sort. Plus, the browser settings are not an actual URL like regular pages you can go to, they are handled by the browser itself.
For more information, check out these links:

- [Link to a browser's settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557651/link-to-a-browsers-settings)
- [Why can't I open the chrome settings page from javascript](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171572/why-cant-i-open-the-chrome-settings-page-from-javascript)

You can ask them to change their settings but cannot link them to it directly.

By the way, [this is for all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557651/link-to-a-browsers-settings), not just Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the Chrome settings page does not open when clicking the link in the HTML code A is because the href attribute in the  tag specifies a URL to navigate to, and `chrome://settings/content/popups` is not a valid URL that can be accessed through the web.

To open the Chrome settings page from an HTML link, you can try and use the [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) API to interact with the browser's tab system.

Comment: I am pretty sure this will only work for Google Chrome so it is better to steer away from this method as it will not work for all users

Comment: Yes the chrome.tabs API is specific to Google Chrome and may not work in other browsers, an alternative approach like you mentioned would be to provide clear instructions to the user on how to access the Chrome settings page.